# Navigation in windows phone7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

What kind of navigation is best suited for a home button in an application,Can any please help me,I am newbie?

Comment: qn is not clear? what do u mean by a home button? Explain your requirement clearly

Comment: clicking the home button navigates to the first page from any page.every page has a home button.

Comment: Windows Phone applications typically use a hub and spoke navigation model and use the back button to return to the previous screen. A "Home" button on every page is unnecessary and often an indication of an attempt to port an application from another platform without fully understanding how WP is different or what is appropriate and common in a WP app.

Comment: Use your app bar to place a home btn as appbar button in all the pages you need to navigate to the home page. That will also meet the WP guidelines to some extent

Comment: Its like opening another page in the stack.But I wanted is closing all the pages and it should come to the first page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked.

1. Globally I declared a Boolean variable set to false in a class.
2. Then whenever the home button is clicked bool variable is set as true and navigated back.

   ```
   Modules.HomeClick = true;
   NavigationService.GoBack();
   ```
3. Then in every page for page loaded event I checked condition if bool variable true go back.

   ```
   if (Modules.HomeClick=true)
   this.NavigationService.GoBack();
   ```

these done in every page till homepage.This do not store backstack.

Answer (score 1):

Updated Answer based on your comments, First you need to create a button(preferably an Appbar button) and then place this code in the click event handler

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Home.xaml?home=true", UriKind.Relative));
```

And then in the Home page in the `onNavigatedTo` event handler place this code

```
string home;
NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("home", out home);
if(home != null)
{
    if (home.Equals("true"))
        while(NavigationService.CanGoBack)
           NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
}
```

So this clears all your back stack

Note: This is not any preferable or recommended way, its just a workaround!!

Comment: thank u chandra,Is there any other way that is preferable avoiding back stack?

Comment: There seems to be no preferable way bcoz it doesn't comply with the WP design guidelines

Answer (score 0):

Add a button in every page (since you want to go home from every page) put the onClick to do:

```
NavigationService.Navigate("YoursView/HomePage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to review the following MSDN documentation regarding Application Structure and Navigation Models :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202909(v=vs.92).aspx