# how to make or create a back button on windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I've made an application, but I have a problem with the back button. When pressed, it returns the user to the home page instead of the previous page.

How can I fix this so the back button brings the user to the *previous* page?

Thank you.

Comment: For navigating to the previous page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187944/navigation-in-windows-phone7 for navigating to home page check this out [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187944/navigation-in-windows-phone7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187944/navigation-in-windows-phone7)

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? The back button on the Phone should work, what is not working, can you show us a minimal example?

Comment: I mean when I press the arrow , he goes to the main page and not on previous ... Should we say something? I do not have to add something application ... I speak for navigation. i dont want to back main page ,,but previous page..

Answer (score 1):

the back button on the device should take you back to the previous page unless you've written code to navigate elsewhere in the 'OnBackKeyPressed' event. If u want to go back to the previous page on some other event try NavigationService.GoBack().